# A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

Hello i am getting this error when i access same method of generic repository twice inside one method.

```
var polyTables = _vehicleService.GetAll().ToList()
                    .Select(p => new PolyTable
                     {
                         VinNumber = p.ChassisNumber ?? "-",
                         BrandName = p.BrandName,
                         FirstRegisterDate = p.FirstRegistrationDate,
                         ModelCode = p.ModelCode,
                         Plate = p.Plate ?? "-",
                         CreatedBy = 1,
                         IsActive = true,
                         AuthorizedServiceId = p.AuthorizedServiceId,
                         Customer = GetLastCustomerName(p.Id, periodicCodes)
                     }).ToList();
```

[Heres My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wmz1.png)

```
 private string GetLastCustomerName(string vehicleId,IEnumerable<PeriodicCode> periodicCodes)
        {
            var invoices = _invoiceService.GetByVehicle(vehicleId);
            var lastInvoiceLine = _invoiceLineService.GetLastInvoiceLineByInvoices(invoices, periodicCodes);
            var customer =new Customer();
            if (lastInvoiceLine != null )
            customer = _customerService.GetById(lastInvoiceLine.CustomerNumber);

            return customer.Name + " " + customer.SurName;
        }
```

Heres me Generic Repository Method

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        if (includes == null)
            return Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        else
            return includes.Aggregate(Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable(), (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
```

Heres GetByVehicle Method

```
public IEnumerable<Invoice> GetByVehicle(string vehicleId) =>
    _genericRepository.Find(s => s.VehicleId == vehicleId);
```

Comment: You are not just executing a single query. You are executing both a SQL query and doing stuff in-memory when reading the results from that SQL query. In the in-memory stuff you are executing another SQL query, and that is not allowed in the same connection.

Comment: Try: `var invoices = _invoiceService.GetByVehicle(vehicleId).ToArray();` in your `GetLastCustomerName` method. You are using the invoices (a query at the moment, not a result) as a parameter in you `GetLastInvoiceLineByInvoices` method-call.

Comment: Tried ToArray Still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing IEnumerable To list here

```
public InvoiceLine GetLastInvoiceLineByInvoices(List<Invoice> invoices, List<InvoiceLine> invoiceLine)
{
    if (invoices != null)
    {
       return invoiceLine.Where(s => s.WorkmanshipId != null && invoices.Select(p=> p.Id).Contains(s.InvoiceId) ).OrderByDescending(s=> s.InvoiceDate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Maartens comment helped alot.